# Yii2 - Query with Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, yii2

I have a Category model that has a relation with the Products model.
I am doing the following query:

```
$model = Category::find()->where(['slug' => $slug])->with('products')->one();
```

And in the view I can retrieve all the products that belong to that Category with:

```
foreach ($model->products as $value)...
```

Now I want to do the pagination in the products but I can not find how to do it in the "with" part of the query.

Comment: Why you don't use dataProvider?

Comment: You can use ActiveDataProvider or ArrayDataProvider and then use pagination property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

In Controller:

```
...
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $model->products->count()]);
return $this->render('index', [
         'model' => $model,
         'pages' => $pages,
    ]);
```

In View:

```
foreach ($model->products as $value) {
    // display $model here
}

// display pagination
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```